# What is dataflow Coder for List<Entity>?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Currently I am trying to override "getDefaultOutputCoder" function, it returns ListCoder.of(EntityCoder). EntityCoder is not recognized. Do we have to specify CUSTOM coder for this? If so, how do we do that?

Comment: Please do not override getDefaultOutputCoder - it is deprecated and it will be deleted in the next major-version Beam release. Instead, call .setCoder() on the returned PCollection (from the transform that produces the collection).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListCoder.of(SerializableCoder.of(Entity.class))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.